# Gitorious error message: Agent admitted failure to sign using the key

Tags: ubuntu, git, version-control

Trying out gitorious I hit a road-block in the form of this error message:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Found a workaround here http://identi.ca/conversation/32495642, and will post it as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as mentioned here http://identi.ca/conversation/32495642 the workaround (or maybe this is the standard protocol?) is to use `ssh-add`.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/adam/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

After doing that, the following command uploaded the files to the remote repository:

```
$ git push origin master
```